# “full site” view has clipped “More” menu

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, responsive-design, iphone

On iPhone, go to the “full site” view and look at “Questions” view. The button bar shows “Newest”, “Active”, etc. When screen is small (or text is large), there’s a More button. Clicking it brings up a menu. But the top item, “Bountied” is clipped by the top menu and cannot be clicked. See image. 
[image: clipped screen shot]

Comment: Related note: turning the phone sideways does not expand the More menu, so there is no workaround within the UI that I can find.

Comment: Happens on my iPhone 7 in Safari. What device are you on exactly?

Comment: I use an iPhone SE

Comment: "Full site" means you're seeing the responsive design. (Explaining tag edit)

Comment: @SRM as a workaround, try clicking "Disable Responsiveness" in the footer.

Comment: @shadow9 that would defeat the whole point of turning on “full site” in the first place. Cutting off a leg is not a workaround for a small cut on my toe.

Comment: Coming back to this, I'm unable to reproduce this. @SRM is this still an issue for you?

Answer (score 3):

Tried reproducing this with a few others and wasn't able to. If this comes up again, please let us know!

Comment: Does not reproduce after recent iPhone OS patch.